# How can I control the usage of a custom jar library?

Tags: java, android

I need a way to essentially secure my jar library to allow registered apps to use it in their projects and deny usage to apps that weren't approved by me.

It is fine if I hard code things in the lib for each distribution. I currently have this jar obfuscated.

What are good approaches to restrict the usage of a jar?

One idea was to lock the lib to a specific package so if the developer tries to use it in another project they can't.  But I'm not sure if they can easily provide a custom fake Context to make it work...

Comment: One problem with security-through-obscurity is that if you talk about how you are going to do it, it's not that obscure any more.

Comment: Very true... However I'm not familiar with this area at all.  I'm essentially expecting to read something that I can further dig. Cause I'm not too familiar with words describing what I want to do...  for example I just learned there is something called Licensing management :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the best approach if you would like your library to stay standalone (without involving the network for checking or downloading pieces of the library, I mean) would be to make mandatory the use of an initializer class that would receive a token from the client application.

**This would be crackable** as the token validity test would be performed by your lib: one may modify the lib in a way is would just skip that test, but this would be made harder by the obfuscation. But this is probably sufficient, unless using your lib without having registered it  is a really critical issue.

- So you would have something like:

  ```
  boolean Initializer.initLib(String passcode)
  ```

That would prevent the lib to work unless `passcode` is correct.

You can make the obfuscation more efficient by avoiding checking that way:

```
public void initLib(String passcode) {
    if (passcode == A_GIVEN_PUBLIC_STATIC_THAT_STORESTHE_CODE) {
         // do the proper initializations 
    }
    else {
         throw new RuntimeException("Bad passcode, sorry!");
    }
}
```

But doing that way instead:

```
public void initLib(String passcode) {
    final char[] PASS_ENCRYPTED  = "f5uhjgf56ik8kv214d5".toCharArray();
    final char[] PASS_MINUSMASK  = "bc".toCharArray();
    final int    PASS_SHIFT      = 11;
    final int    PASS_MASK_MINUS = 2;

    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < PASS_MINUSMASK.length; ++ctr) {  
        final char next = PASS_ENCRYPTED[PASS_SHIFT + ctr - PASS_MASK_MINUS];

        if (passcode.charAt(ctr) != next - (PASS_MINUSMASK[ctr] - 'a')) {
            // make the lib unusable by some inits. But it should look as a proper initialization
            return;
        }
    }    

    // make the lib usable by some inits.
}
```

This looks stupid, but if you have a look at the obfuscated code, you will see a big difference. This code is just an example (it accepts "hi" as a valid passcode), any algorithm would be fine as long as its obfuscated version is not too straightforward to reverse.

- Now the question is: what passcode?

As the library's protection concerns the developpers of the client apps that will use it, and not the final users of these apps, you cannot rely on any piece of data specific to the devices on which the applications will run. So no IMEI or anything like that.

If these developpers are trustworthy that's fine. A fixed passcode is sufficient.

But if they are subject to give this passcode to other people to allow them using your library, this is more difficult. In this case I don't think you can solve it without a real "industrial" process such as registering the client apps and their code checksums, for example. Such a process needs a specific design and cannot be solved "just by the code", but as it also has a cost (time, resources, involvment of the client...) you can only consider this if the use of library is very critical.

Comment: Thanks for your post.  It is definitely helping me understand more the concept of protecting software library.

Comment: Thanks! Well, this explains only a part of it. You can consider more advanced ways such as having a registration server that would check the usage of the lib at each use, etc, but this is definitely more costly. Let's say this is the 1st level: a basic protection fine to prevent the most obvious cases. Also, don't forget to change the implementation of your protection every time you release. This way, any non registered user will have to re-break your lib or to get its passcode again to be able to use the new version you will have published.

Comment: This article, also, is very interesting (and shows the limits of software protection): http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html - This is about the Android's Licencing Library but the same principles can be applied to yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you make your jar call your server with a specific code and the application name, to check if they are registered ?

Comment: Normally, I'd say this is the right answer. If you can be reasonably certain that the library will be used in apps which already will require Internet permission, then this is the way to go. Of course, you still have the issue of getting the package name that the library is used in, and since getPackageName() can be overridden you can't trust it.

Comment: I agree with nEx.Software.  Thanks alocaly for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you build an Android app with a jar, that jar is compiled into the app and becomes a part of it. You can't just copy the jar out of the package and use it elsewhere. Unless I'm not understanding the question, this shouldn't be an issue you need to worry about.

Comment: Well essentially what I'm doing is creating an obfuscated jar that people can include on their applications.  This part is fine and works perfectly.  What I want to do is restrict the usage of the jar.  So for example I gave a jar build particularly for app com.app.company  I don't want the jar to work if the package of the application is different.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm not sure why that didn't register with me. Now that you clarified I can see exactly where it says that in the first post. Doh. I'd imagine this is less an Android issue and more a license issue. I mean, you could take a Context and use getPackageName() but if they want they can override getPackageName() to return anything they want.

Comment: No problem... Yes, in regards to overidding getPackageName() could potentially easily happen... Maybe I could verify package name by writing to cache or something...